# Loop which skips string after colorized

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hi i need to do loop which colorize  words, one after another. Sadly this loop:

```
slowa = ["Marek", "Hłaska", "biega", "nago", "jak", "kiełbaska"]
for slowa in slowa:
    print (colored(slowa, "green"))
    print (colored(slowa, "red"))
```

Doubles the output:[:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Vq2.png)

I want to colorize every word in different color in loop. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
slowa = ["Marek", "Haska", "biega", "nago", "jak", "kiebaska"]
color=['green','red']
le = len(color)
for ind,slowa in enumerate(slowa):
    print (colored(slowa,color[ind%le]))
```